# Triggering an event listener in a textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with a textbox on it and every time you release a key it "checks" if it matches the correct word with a listener (I think). What I have done so far is change the value of the textbox with ".value". Now I would like to trigger that listener that checks the validity of the textbox but I can not get it to work. Here is the HTML.

```
<input type="text" no-translate="true" class="word-textbox word-normal" data-bind="value: currentWord().wordEntry, keyPress: currentWord().OnKeyPress, css: currentWord().wordStatus, enable: enableTextboxes">
```

And now my javascript.

```
var normalTextBox = document.getElementsByClassName("word-textbox word-normal")[0];
var normalTextButton = document.getElementsByClassName("plainbtn alt blue selected")[0];
normalTextBox.value = normalTextButton.innerHTML;
normalTextBox.trigger();
```

And this gives me the error "normalTextBox.trigger is not a function".
Also, the listener is called keyUp.

Comment: `trigger` is a jQuery function not a native JS function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textbox element does not have a `trigger` function natively. You will need to use `dispatchEvent`. Here is a little snippet I've used before.

```
function triggerEvent(el, type) {
  if ('createEvent' in document) {
        // modern browsers, IE9+
        var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.initEvent(type, false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(e);
  } else {
        // IE 8
        var e = document.createEventObject();
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
  }
}
```

And in your case you would use...

```
var normalTextBox = document.getElementsByClassName("word-textbox word-normal")[0];
var normalTextButton = document.getElementsByClassName("plainbtn alt blue selected")[0];
normalTextBox.value = normalTextButton.innerHTML;
triggerEvent(normalTextBox, "keyup");
//or
triggerEvent(normalTextBox, "change");
```

Comment: Yep, I sure did. Thanks.

Comment: I think what he's looking for is `change` event not `keyup`